# Gap function that returns the integer distance between first appearance of two elements in a list using either foldl or foldr.(Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, fold

the type is defined as follows:
gap :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
I have been stuck on this problem for more than an hour and have no idea how to approach the problem. I am aware that it requires the use of fold and am familiar with that topic.
Please take into consideration that either foldl or foldr must be used.
The output when called ought to look like this

> gap 3 8 [1..10]
>   =Just 5
>
> gap 8 3 [1..10]
>   =Nothing
>
> gap 'h' 'l' "hello"
>   =Just 2
>
> gap 'h' 'z' "hello"
>   =Nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might `dropWhile` the list until you find the starting element and then fold from the right, starting with `Nothing`, replacing that with `Just 1` once you hit the end element, and `fmap`ing `+1` to the accumulator. In code:

```hs
gap :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
gap from to xs = case dropWhile (/= from) xs of
                      [] -> Nothing
                      (_:rest) -> gap' to rest

gap' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
gap' to = foldr f Nothing
    where f x acc | x == to = Just 1
                  | otherwise = (+1) <$> acc
```

The nice thing is that it works correctly if you have several occurences of the elements in your sequence:

```
*Main> gap 3 8 $ [1..10] ++ [1..10]
Just 5
*Main> gap 3 8 [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8]
Just 3
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but is there any way to include only the following concepts as I am new and still learning and exploring haskell. The following concepts include: Tuple construction & component access: (), fst, snd
List construction & access: [], (:), head, tail, init, last, (!!), (++)
Boolean operators: not, (&&), (||)
Composition: (.)
Arithmetic: (+), (-), (/), (*)
Comparison: (==), (/=), (<), (<=), (>), (>=)
HOFs: map, foldr, foldl

Comment: That is a strangely specific list of requirements. Is this homework?

Comment: @ Rein Henrichs It was assigned as homework but the due date has passed, so I am trying to figure out how to solve it for my own benefit. The provided list of functions above were the only concepts that were taught in class, therefore our professor expected us to use the knowledge we had on those topics only to answer the homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solution isn't nice, but it works

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Function
import Data.Foldable     

(...) = (.) . (.)
gap x y = liftA2 ((guard . (> 0) =<<) ... liftA2 (subtract `on` fst)) 
                 (find ((==x) . snd)) (find((==y) . snd)) . zip [0..]
```