# How would I find the distance between two elements in a list?

Tags: haskell

I have to find the distance between first appearance of two elements in a list. The program we are using is Haskell. I've been online for HOURS trying to look for help on how to start or direction to solve it. Please help!

This is how we are defining it:
`gap :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`

Here are some examples:

```
> gap 3 8 [1..10]
Just 5

> gap 8 3 [1..10]
Nothing

> gap 'h' 'l' "hello"
Just 2

> gap 'h' 'z' "hello"
Nothing
```

Comment: have a look at the `Data.List` library https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html , there are many different approaches to problems like this that depend on how much you want/have to write your own functions from scratch

Comment: Also remember you can look for function by types on Hoogle https://hoogle.haskell.org/, so in this case you would want a function that, given an element and a list, returns its index: `a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`

Comment: Hi Lola, have you looked through the functions in Data.List? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html . The `break` function might be useful.  Are you haveing trouble with using recursion? Try looking at some existing recursive code and make sure ytou know how recursion works in haskell.

Comment: What would `gap 'a' 'a' "a"` be? `Just 0` or `Nothing`? How about `gap 'a' 'a' "aa"`? `Just 0` or `Just 1`?

Comment: `gap' x1 x2 = length . takeWhile (/= x2) . dropWhile (/= x1)` is a good starting point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gap function that returns the integer distance between first appearance of two elements in a list using either foldl or foldr.(Haskell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246572/gap-function-that-returns-the-integer-distance-between-first-appearance-of-two-e)

Comment: @AaditMShah, I would reach for `elemIndex` for the second part.

Comment: The alleged duplicate specifically asks for a fold.

Comment: Why does  `gap 8 3 [1..10]` not return `Just 5`?

Answer (score 3):

An answer which is expected to run fast:

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)


gap :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
gap x y ls = elemIndex y $ dropWhile ((/=) x) ls
```

If you do not want to rely on `Data.List` then you have to write and add your own `elemIndex'`.

After Daniel Wagner's feedback an alternative:

```
gap' :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
gap' x y ls
    | null ls'          = Nothing
    | head ls' == y     = Nothing 
    | otherwise         = elemIndex y ls'

    where

    ls' = dropWhile (\t -> t /= x && t /= y) ls
```

Comment: Same comment as I gave dfeuer: this does not appear to comply to the spec. Consider e.g. `gap 'a' 'b' "bacb"` -- this reports `Just 2`, which is clearly incorrect. (`Nothing`, `Just 1`, or `Just (-1)` all might be sensible choices depending on exactly how you interpret the spec.)

Comment: Just 2 seems correct to me @Daniel . The second example case indicates that the second argument should appear in the list at or beyond the first argument. On "bacb" then gap 'a' 'a' is Just 0, gap 'a' 'c' is Just 1, gap 'a' 'b' is Just 2

Comment: @ATayler The second example's return value is not a `Just`, so I don't see how you can use it to support returning a `Just` in some other case.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think I get got why we're misunderstanding each other. My spec is, "find the first occurrence o of the first argument, then *only considering the remainder of the list subsequent to that first occurrence* find the first occurrence of the second argument, then subtract their indices, returning Nothing if either is not to be found". Your spec is "find the first occurrence of each argument o1 o2 and return if o1 <= o2 then Just (o2 - o1) else Nothing". Both of which are consistent with the examples given, I think mine is a marginally more natural interpretation but you mayn't.

Comment: @ATayler I think your claim about my interpretation of the spec is too precise, since I don't know what to return in case `o1 <= o2` (e.g. it seems as though always returning `Just (o2-o1)` when `o1` and `o2` both exist matches the examples, too). But yes, I interpret "first appearance of two elements" as "first occurrence of each argument". Perhaps some extra condition like the one you propose was *intended*, but no extra condition was *stated*, and the example input-output pairs don't imply one.

Comment: @DanielWagner My strongest argument is that the two arguments should be provided in an unordered fashion were your behaviour intended, but probably that's a stretch :P. I think you mean you don't know what to do in case `o2 <= o1` though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```hs
import Data.List (elemIndex)

gap :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
gap x1 x2 xs = do
    i <- elemIndex x1 xs
    j <- elemIndex x2 xs
    if i <= j
        then Just (j - i)
        else Nothing
```

Credits to [dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) for reminding me of the [`elemIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex) function.

Comment: This is gratuitously inefficient. `dropWhile` was the right way to start.

Comment: @dfeuer I think it is about as efficient as can be done given the spec. If I have correctly guessed what you have in mind for `dropWhile`, it will get the wrong answer for `gap 'a' 'b' "bacb"`. (Whether the code in the answer gets it right or not is not clear -- the spec is a bit ambiguous, I have to say -- but the `dropWhile` version will definitely get it wrong!)

Comment: @DanielWagner, it seems a bit ambiguous, but I see what you mean. However, it's still not the best way, because it traverses the list twice, retaining memory. You could use a slightly different `dropWhile` invocation, or to avoid a redundant test work up something custom.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree. Without optimizations, this code is very inefficient. However, a smart compiler could most probably perform loop fusion to traverse the list only once. Either way, the first step is to get the program right, and the next step is to perform optimizations if necessary. If it doesn't matter that this code is inefficient, then let it be. However, if you find out that it's a performance bottleneck only then should you bother optimizing it.